# Reactive programming, mapping an array of objects to an array of just one object field?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am new to RXJS, what would be the better reactive approach to:

```
this.names$ = this.updates$.map(objects => objects.map((object) => object['name']));
```

Answer (score 0):

**RxJs** is **lazy**. It means that if you don't call `subscribe` it won't do anything.

Assuming `this.updates$` is an `Observable`:

```js
this.updates$.map(objects => objects.json())
             .subscribe(x => this.names$ = x.aField.map(obj => obj['name']));
```

`aField` is the field of your response structure where the `array of object` is stored.